# why doesn't it work when there is no space at the beginning of the string?

Tags: c

```
void RemoveSpaces(char *source){
  char* i=source;
  char* j = source;
  while(*j == ' '){
    j++;
  }
  while(*j!=0){
    *i++ = *j++;
  }

  /*edit:didn't work because 'i' pointed '\0'. İf we add here (i--;), will work */
  i--;//edit1.
  while(*i==' '){
    i--;
  }
  *++i='\0';
}
```

it works correctly when there is a space at the beginning and end of the string, but it doesn't work properly if there is no space at the beginning.Why?

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYhYV.png)

Comment: You expect `i` to point at the end of the string before staring the last loop, but this is not necessarily the case here. If there are no leading spaces it will point at the null terminator just like `j` does.

Comment: Kindly try to avoid posting codes and outputs as images. As much as possible add them as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void RemoveSpaces(char *source){
  char* i=source;
  char* j = source;
  while(*j == ' '){
    j++;
  }
```

When there are no leading spaces, i and j will be (and remain) the same.

```
  while(*j!=0){
    *i++ = *j++;
  }
```

Your loop stopped at the zero terminator. Therefore you need to go backwards from there using j, not i:

Added the check for zero-length strings.

```
  if(j > source){
     while(*--j == ' ');

//      while(*i==' '){
//        i--;
//      }
```

And also use j to put in the null-terminator.

```
   *++j='\0';
   }
//      *++i='\0';
}
```

Comment: `while(*--j == ' ');` -- this has undefined behavior when `source` points to an empty string.

Comment: @XLVII Dont forget my last edit as pointed out by David Bowling